# How to convert JSON property array to Array of strings Object in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, post

I currently have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "Id": ["1", "2"],
  "Settings": [{ "Key": "IgnitionOn", "Value": "true" }]
}
```

I want to be able to access Id and convert it to an Array of strings in node.js. Namely, what I want to do is access Id using `req.body.Id`. This works when Id is just a string. If I try to access `req.body.Id` currently, I get it to be undefined. I have also tried `JSON.parse(req.body.Id)` and `JSON.stringify(req.body.Id)` but in both approaches, the Ids are still undefined. Given my req body above, any suggestions on how I can create an instance of an array that is precisely the Id array in the body?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: can you try to log `req.body.Id`?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse this JSON to get an object:

```
const result = JSON.pasrse(req.body)
const id = result.id;
```

Comment: Is there a way to cast that object to an array? Currently, when I do what's suggested above, `id` is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you body is in JSON, you will need to parse then entire body with `JSON.parse(req.body)` before accessing the `.Id` field

```
let req = {
    body: `{
        "Id": ["1","2"],
        "Settings": [{"Key": "IgnitionOn", "Value": "true"}]
        }`
}
let body = JSON.parse(req.body)
let ids = body.Id
console.log(ids)
// [ '1', '2' ]
```

Comment: When I try this approach, I get the error thrown: "Cannot convert object to primitive value." What would that mean in this case? Further to this `ids` as defined above is still undefined for me...